# Bitflow Framegrabber Support for .net 6 or later or C++ DllImport examples

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net-core-6.0

My task is to control and capture data from a device using an existing .net 6 application via hardware and software that was partially selected for .net compatibility.

> While it's not the point of this question it MUST be noted that
> qualified technical planners can too easily be thrown off by the .net
> ecosystem naming thrash where from 2002-2015 or so the accepted meaning of the term ".net" implied
> 'framework' with years of SEO results, and now it's just ".net" after
> 'core' and sort of 'standard' making it near impossible to verify
> years of libraries and existing code for relevant modern
> compatibility.

Bitflow has a .net SDK, but without a nuget package (so without the explicit ability to determine target runtime support). Inspection of example code reveals it targets 4.8 framework.

[image: bitflow sdk]
https://www.bitflow.com/current-downloads/

[image: BufferAcquisition 4.8]

It also appears that the SDK examples reference a 'managed' lib "ManagedBufferAcquisition.dll" which shows dependencies on dotpeek as well as C++? dependencies from Dependency Walker. I think all my method goodness is in here.

How I can access it from .net 6? I am slightly aware and have tried the DllImport attribute but immediately get memory access violations and have no idea how more complex input output objects would work.

[image: Buffer Acquisition dll]
[image: ManagedBufferInterface]
[image: DLL Import]
[image: Access Violation]

Comment: You need to install the version of Net the SDK is using or recompile.  Code looks like it is using Net 4.0.  With Net 4.0 it is only an incremental library.  So you also have to install Net 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5.  Starting with Net 4.3 you only have to install one version of Net.

Comment: @jdweng Thx! Might be one option, and the sad state of .net, to use an old lib on .net 6, run it side by side with 4.8 framework? Not to mention other gotchas of 2nd order deps between them. I'm hoping for a better option, but good call out.

Comment: You only have two options.  Either install the older versions of Net or upgrade code to new version of Net/Core.  You can't run an old net version without the same net libraries installed.

Comment: Testing with 4.0 and 4.8 installed doesn't work (which makes sense that .net 6 self contained can't properly resolve 4.8 stuff, especially from a 3rd party lib) and throws the same run time errors on suspected unresolved dependencies. Bitflow did respond in an email and confirmed no support beyond .net 4.8, but it is on their to do list and will get back on the schedule. We are ditching .net for this driver and using the working samples from python.

Comment: See page 148 : https://www.adlinktech.com/Products/Download.ashx?type=MDownload&isManual=yes&file=814%5CPCIe-CPL64_50-11158-1020_202.pdf